# Developing Windows Software on Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, windows

I am making software for windows that uses things like windows api and I really do not like developing on windows.

Is there a way to develop software on Linux, for Windows, preferably without virtual machines as my computer is not very powerful, I am using C/C++.

Comment: You might want to try to set up a [wine](https://www.winehq.org/) environment to run your code (and IDE)

Comment: If you engineer your application to have a user-interface agnostic "engine" as a separate logical module to the user interface, you could do a lot of the work (the engine) on Linux and just do the GUI stuff in Windows.

Comment: Think hard about the test/debug cycles of your development and how much more difficult they will be under wine or similar.

Comment: @Galik's suggestion is the most reasonable approach 99% of the time for cross-platform development.

Comment: My app requires windows api to work so I sadly cant save it for the end. I don't think there is a good way to do this besides virtual machines but I remain hopeful for a solution in the future.

Comment: @Mintybits not only do you need a compiler that can produce Windows executables, but you also need a copy of the Windows SDK in order to use Windows APIs in your code. While the former *might* exist for non-Windows systems, AFAIK the latter is only available for Windows systems, so you need a Windows system to develop on, whether it is in a VM or not.

Comment: Building on what @Galik said, you could also make an abstraction layer for the required windows API and either implement them using the linux equivalent system calls on linux, or provide a dummy implementation on linux. Then you can develop most of the functionality on linux before going back to windows to verify.

Comment: I would like to hear your opinions on "gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64" for cross compilation it seems to work but I am not too sure about it.

Comment: @Mintybits.  You can use mingw-w64 with `-mwindows` to create windows executables and without `-mwindows` to create windows console apps - it is just a GCC compiler for windows.  I personally like the one from https://winlibs.com/ since it also has the unix command line utilities.

Comment: While it is certainly possible to cross-compile Windows software on linux, debugging and testing it properly would still require running Windows.

Comment: Target Wine, and use a Windows VM to verify often that your program is compatible with the real Windows.

Comment: It should be easy to install a cross-compiler (and libraries, etc) to allow you to develop Windows software on native Linux (most Linux distros provide Mingw via. their package system). Testing under Wine should also be relatively easy. The only real problem would be dealing with differences between Windows and Wine (you'd still have to test on Windows occasionally in case, preferably several versions of Windows - e.g. Win 8 and Win 10), and attaching a source level debugger to your process while testing under Wine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably no universal answer to this.

This is how I develop software on Linux that is used mainly on Windows:

1. I use the Qt framework which abstracts away all platform-dependent details in my case.
2. I use [MinGW-w64](https://www.mingw-w64.org/) to cross-compile. It works very well with CMake-based projects and the excellent [binaries from Martchus](https://github.com/Martchus/PKGBUILDs/blob/master/qt5-base/mingw-w64-static/README.md), which also have great support for static builds.
3. I use Wine for testing. However during development I can test and debug the Linux binary. A luxury due to Qt abstraction that fits my needs.